# Convert QString to a Xerces string

Tags: c++, string, qt, qt4, xerces-c

I want to convert a [QString](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qstring.html) to an `XMLCh const *` to be used by Xerces-C++.

The former can be "transformed" to a NUL-terminated `const ushort *` in host byte-order in (I think) O(1) time. The latter is also a UTF-16 string, but I'm not sure in which byte-order.

Has anyone tackled this problem before? I don't feel like doing lots of string copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
const XMLCh* QtoX(const QString& s) { return (s.utf16()); }
QString XtoQ(const XMLCh* x) { return QString::fromUtf16(x); }
```

from [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/c-dev@xerces.apache.org/msg01745.html)? I have no personal experience with this.

Comment: I'd figured something similar to this, but I can't find in the Xerces-C docs whether it expects host byte-order or network byte-order.

Comment: A bit of Googling turned up this: http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/yh2do8NlHXpwlbtrr0Uj

Comment: Ah, hadn't seen that. Thanks! (Also here: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xerces-c-users/201007.mbox/%3C4C4B2776.7020000@apache.org%3E)

Comment: Always better from the source :)

Answer (score -2):

```
QString->XMLCh*  QString::toWCharArray(XMLCh* buffer)
XMLCh->QString   QString::fromWCharArray(x)
```

Allocate a memory for XMLCh:

```
XMLCh* QString2X(QString _w, MemoryManager *mm =
                 XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager) {
   XMLCh b[256];
   _w.toWCharArray(b);
   XMLCh* _x = (XMLCh*) mm->allocate((XMLString::stringLen(b)+1)*sizeof(XMLCh));  
   XMLString::copyString(_x, b);
   return _x; 
}
```